# SCORING in Android (Adding Continuously and Saving Score for HighScore)

Tags: java, android

Below is the code I use. Its working til 3 clicks only  the succeeding clicks doesn't add "continuously" like the normal scoring in a game. Another problem is that I don't know how to save the score after the time is up. I am thinking of using the data (saved score) for displaying the best score at the end of every game. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 //CALCULATE SCORE
    //declare a boolean variable for score
    private int optionTxtView = 0  ;
    private int addClick = 0  ;



    private void calculate(){
        x = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
        y = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
        z = x + y;
        score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
    }

    private void calculate2(){
        x = Integer.parseInt(score2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
        y = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
        z = x + y;
        score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
    }

    private void calculate3(){
        x = Integer.parseInt(score2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
        y = Integer.parseInt(score3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
        z = x + y;
        score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
    }

     //search 
    public void viewWord(View view)
    {   
        String s1= search.getText().toString();
        String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);

        if(optionTxtView == 0){
        //display the score on textview1
            tv2.setText(s2);
            optionTxtView = 1;

            }
        else{
            if(optionTxtView == 1){
        //display the score on textview2    
            tv3.setText(s2);
            optionTxtView = 0;
            }
        }

        adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        text.clearComposingText();    

      //clicks = calculate to be use
        if(addClick == 0){
            calculate();
            score2.setText(score.getText());
            addClick = 1;
            text.clearComposingText();

        }
        else{
            if(addClick == 1){
                calculate();
                score2.setText(score.getText());
                addClick = 2;
                text.clearComposingText();

            }
            else{
                if(addClick == 2){
                    calculate2();
                    score2.setText(score.getText());
                    addClick = 3;
                    text.clearComposingText();
                }
                else{
                    if(addClick == 3){
                        calculate3();
                        score3.setText(score.getText());
                        addClick = 2;
                        text.clearComposingText();
                    }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to see what you're expecting to happen and the difference between the various text boxes and calculate methods.

Answer (score 1):

to save the scoer you can use SharedPrefrences:

to save your score:
(gameData is the string to later use to get the sharedPrefrences)

```
SharedPreferences myData= getSharedPreferences("gameData", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myData.edit();
editor.putInt("gameScore", myGameScore);
editor.commit;
```

to load your score:

```
SharedPreferences myData= getSharedPreferences("gameData", 0);
int myScore = myData.getInt(gameScore, 0);
```

after doing so, "myScore" will contain the score that you save (or 0 for default value if you didn't save any score before).

about the first part of your question  - I didn't andestood what you asked...

Comment: hi where should i put this code? What i mean on my first question is that the score only adds correctly 3 times(upon finding each word) @DvirItzko

Comment: The first part oc the cide you out in the part if your code after retrieving the users score.

The second part you put in tye part when you want to load the score..

Comment: i'm sorry i cant understand your reply.